# Enable/Disable graph series with listbox selection

Tags: c#, charts, listbox

I am trying to control the displayed series on a line graph in c# using a listbox (lb) selection.

```
private void lbSERIES_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int item_count = 0;
        foreach (var item in lbSERIES.Items)
        {

            if (lbSERIES.SelectedItems.Contains(item))
            {
                chart1.Series[item_count + 2].Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                chart1.Series[item_count + 2].Enabled = false;
            }
            item_count++;
        } // end for each item check 
    } // end selection changed
```

However when the code gets to this part I get the error message

> Unhandled Exception ... List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. an enumerator can only be used if the list does not change

I am not sure what is causing this issue. From what I understand I am not changing the listbox items during the foreach loop. What is causing this error and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to substitute the foreach with a for.

While a foreach executes, you can't manipulate the collection's items

```
private void lbSERIES_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lbSERIES.Items.Count; i++)
        {    
            if (lbSERIES.SelectedItems.Contains(lbSERIES.Items[i]))
            {
                chart1.Series[i + 2].Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                chart1.Series[i + 2].Enabled = false;
            }
        } // end for each item check 
    } // end selection changed
```

Comment: I am manipulating another collection (the chart). The code does not compile with "for" instead of "foreach". are there any other modification to be made?

Comment: It must compile this way, what's the problem?